# Android Offline Webapp Resources

Tags: iphone, android, html, mobile, web-applications

I just made an offline card game webapp for iPhone and Android  When doing this, I went entirely off of the abundant iPhone offline webapp information on the web.  However, it seems to work perfectly on Android with one exception.  When I open it after killing the web connection, it states an error about not being able to connect.  After canceling, it works just fine.

My question is this: has anyone found any decent resources specifically regarding Android offline web apps?  Or is this simply a hack?  The iOS devices seems to support this in a more intuitive way.

UPDATE:  I had forgotten about this issue that I posted about.  This seems to have been resolved for a while.  I think it may have been fixed in Android 2.1.  I just seemed to have not noticed that there was no error message.  However, it still does not run HTML 5 webapps as cleanly as iOS in that the nav bar is still present when running from a desktop bookmark.

Comment: Awesome!  Nothing but crickets on this one, but it's cool, because I was rewarded with the "Tumbleweed" badge.  Good times!

Comment: Good find as I am looking to do something similar, too bad there isn't anyone with an answer for this!

Answer (score 2):

After messing with this stuff for a bit, the iPhone/iOS stuff seems to work fine.  It might be because the android browser is webkit based.  But for whatever reason, the file manifest is respected

Bottom line, iPhone HTML5 mobile app documentation seems to work fine for Android.

Here's a quick example that runs on both:

http://www.davidgranado.com/demos/make_a_set_mobile/

Here are the rules:

http://www.davidgranado.com/2010/11/make-a-set-game/