# Why html5 app, don't work offline on my android?

Tags: android, html, web-applications

Hello i have the this problem, i need your help to figure out what i'm missing.

At this page there are a lot of html5 mobile\web applications
http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/30-incredibly-useful-fun-html5-mobile-apps/

Let's take for example this one (a white page where you can draw in)
http://miniapps.co.uk/canvas/

and this one (a list where you can add staff for example when you are at the supermarket and chek things you already found)
http://miniapps.co.uk/checklist/

These apps are working on my pc and also on my android phone if i use them online. Now this is the problem. I'm developping an android app. I have an activity with an invisible browser inside that should run web apps saved on my phone.

So when i find an intersting html5 or html4 app on internet, i would like to save this app on my pc hard disk, move it to my Android phone and use it offline thanks to my android app.
So when i have the app opened inside  my pc browser, i click on file, then save page as and then complete page.

In the case of the Check list app, it downloads these files:
Checklist.html and a folder Checklist_file with inside 4 .js files and 1 .css file.

If i click on Checklist.html it opens the page offline and it works perfectly on my pc, but when i move all these files on my android phone and i click on the html file, it doesn't work anymore. It actually opens the page, shows the app, but i can't interact with it, i can digit a new object name but i can't click the add button, or check and uncheck items.

The same with the canvas app, i can draw, but buttons to save the image or clear the page don't work.

I'd like to know why, if i'm saving apps in the wrong way and why they do work off line on my pc but not on the phone. It's not related to the application i'm developping cause also if i click directly to the html file it opens the browser and the app but the result is the same, i can't fully interact, but when i use them online they work perfectly so it's not an android issue neither.

I really need to be able to run html(or html5) apps offline, cause it's part of a big project.

Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to simply do what your asking but it definitely sounds like you could accomplish that using phone gap. It allows you to write you apps in web based languages like html 5 and javascript and then run them on any device. I just looked at it myself the other day and plan on using it at some point in the future for trimmed down versions of my apps.

http://phonegap.com

Comment: Developping web apps is not part of the project, that's why i'm trying to save them in that way taking already existin apps.....i just need to be able to run web apps offline made by someone else(so they must be phisycally on the phone) on my android device. And right now for some reasons they don't work. I would like to know what's the reason........If i go to the app web page with my android they work but if i open the html file they don't.....Is there an explanation? SHould i save them or get them in another way? Why on my pc the work on both ways?

Comment: are you packaging it as an app in an apk file or are you just opening the html page in you browser?

Comment: this post should help you fix your problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321622/android-offline-webapp-resources    and this link is at this post   http://www.davidgranado.com/demos/make_a_set_mobile/  you can view the source by using the view source tool in your browser. I use chrome so I just left click on it and click view source.

Comment: I'm just opening the html page in my android browser, and when the html file is stored on the device it doesn't work well, but if a go to the web page using internet it works.....i'll read the link to see if it can help.

Comment: There are 2 versione of the app you linked, the mobile one works online and also offline if i download it on my smartphone.....Now i'm more confused than before, why is this one working and the others i linked in the post are not? Is this html5 or standard html? Maybe it works cause it's html standard?

Comment: Im just currious....where on the phone do you store these files? Maybe when you download the other webapp source your missing something...or its expecting something to be somewhere its not. Also it may depend on what type of device your trying this on. Each manufacturer is free to use which ever browser on the phone they want so it maybe that if your using a samsung phone their samsung version of the android browser wont do what you expect it to. Try downloading firefox mobile or dolphin browser both of which are really great mobile browsers for android and see if it works on them.

Comment: I'm downloading them on the phone sd card, in the directoru downloads\html5app.......I'm using a weird phon with cyanogen room mod on it having android 2.3.7 It can't be the browser cause all the apps are working if i go to the website (online).....probably when i download them i miss some files (don't know why) but this doesn't explain cause on my pc are working also offline....

Comment: It could be that the phone browser cant see into the phones file path.....maybe ask around on here about the browsers ability to see html/web pages that are stored locally on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout open the app with your PC browser, hit File->Save Page as->Complete HTML Page. Then copy the files in your phone.

This is fastest work-around for you. Or... you can invest some time learning phonegap. Or java for android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into cache manifests  you find your  answer  there. html5 pages need to  have the correct  parameters set to run offline.